# Checking if a collection exists in Firestore before creating it

Tags: android, firebase, race-condition, google-cloud-firestore

**Context**: My application currently allows users to create an account, with a *username*. Upon clicking `confirm` - to create an account, a check is ran on the *username* to verify that it does not exist as a document within the `usernames` collection *i.e this allows for only unique usernames within the application.*

The usernames were added to a map when the **view** was created - prior to the user pressing the `confirm` button (I understand that this is the underlying issue)

```
public static void getAllNonAvailableUsernames() {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("usernames")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                 List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = task.getResult().getDocuments();
                 for (DocumentSnapshot snap : snapshots) {
                     usedUsernames.put(snap.getId(), snap.get("owner"));
                 }
             });
}
```

**A Problem** arises when two users happen to choose the same username to register with. The last request is processed and overrides the `owner` field within the document, **allowing both users to have the same username** :

[image: Format of the usernames collection]

I'm unsure how to go about solving this issue, since the retrieval of all the documents within the `usernames` collection might not finish before the validation is occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have unique usernames for your users, the only way to do this correctly is with a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction). Within your transaction, read the specific username you're trying to register then:

- If the username exists: ask the user for a different username
- Otherwise set the user record up.

The transaction guarantees that both operations happen atomically.

Note that Firestore transactions only work while online. If you attempt to run a transaction without a network connection it will fail after a few attempts. In this case you'll need to prompt your user to register while they have a network connection.

Comment: I've tried to incorporate this into my application, but I get a 'NOTAUTHENTICATED' error. Also, when following the examples in the docs as reference, I end up with the username document "appearing" as though it exists, so I can't check if it's not there.

Can you provide an example.